# UITableView: last cell is not completely visible

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview

In my custom `UITableViewCell` I set the height of row as

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return 70;
}
```

As a result (I believe), when data is rendered, the last cell is not rendered correctly.

[image]

This happens on all views where I set the `heightForRowAtIndexPath`. How do I fix it, so that I can see last cell as well?

Comment: reduce the height of UITablView instead of UITableViewCell in case you cannot reduce cell height.

Comment: R u using AutoLayouts...?Then set height constraint for tableview..!

Answer (score 2):

You are returning the height of the cell correctly and this issue seems to be related with table view and not with the cell, I think you need to reduce the height of the tableView.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using AutoLayout then you need to set constraints to your tableView with Respect to its superview.

Else if just set

```
[tableView setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingMaskFelxibleHeight | UIViewAutoResizingMaskFlexibleWidth];
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps your UITableView's height is not right, check it.